# desktop-save mode prevents Emacs from refreshing

Tags: desktop, session

I'm using Emacs 29.1 on Windows.

I've found `desktop-save` is problematic. My configuration is:

```
(use-package desktop
  :init
  (setq desktop-dirname             "~/.emacs.d/desktop/"
        desktop-base-file-name      "emacs.desktop"
        desktop-base-lock-name      "lock"
        desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
        desktop-save                t
        desktop-load-locked-desktop nil
        desktop-auto-save-timeout   30
        desktop-restore-eager       t
        )
  :config
)

(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

When I remove these everything works fine, except the session is not saved and restored (obviously). When I enable `desktop-save`, my Emacs can no longer properly redraw itself.

For example, when I activate `magit` with `desktop-save` enabled, it doesn't show up in the other window until I press another key. Which key is doesn't matter: I just have to press *something* otherwise Emacs doesn't redraw and `magit` doesnt show up.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or is there an alternative to `desktop-save`? (I tried disabling `desktop-restore-eager`, but once it loads up the buffers the problem comes back.)

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`